Does the byteman package for Ubuntu not include the shell scripts needed to launch?
JBoss Byteman seems to get compiled down only to jars.
So, are the shell scripts (rather) needed to launch these in a convenient fashion not included by Ubuntu? (If that's the case I should file a RFE somewhere, but I wanted to check I'm not missing something obvious.)

No, the package index doesn't have a file with bmjava anywhere in the name. This also true for upstream Debian, where this library was initially packaged as a dependency of Cassandra. I don't suppose convenience scripts for a dependency library were on the packager's mind.

I'm not sure anything in the repo depends on byteman. It suggests "testng" but that doesn't actually list it as a dependency.

Well, yes, it seems Cassandra was never actually packaged after all. The ITP is still open.
